# Customized bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies

I want to create a bibliography style that print the refrences as in these examples:

> Hannan EJ. 1969. A note on an exact test for trend and serial
>   correlation. Econometrica 37: 485-489.
>
> Hannan EJ, Terrell RD. 1973. Multiple equation systems with stationary
>   errors. Econometrica 41: 299-305.
>
> Johnson HG. 1964a. The international competitive positions of the
>   United States and the balance of payment prospects for 1968. Rev.
>   Economics and Statistics 46: 14-32.
>
> Johnson HG. 1964b. Money, Trade and Economic Growth (2nd edn). London:
>   Allen and Unwin.

Is there a `.bst` file that have a similar style as this? I am using `natbib`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What you have shown looks like any regular Author-Year style.

Comment: @Johannes_B what is the name of this regular style?

Answer (score 1):

I have found it, it's name is `cbe`.